# return product price using LINQ, what return type to use in function?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, compiler-errors

I'm just getting started with LINQ and I'm trying to select and return a product price from database, like so:

```
public int GetPricePerKg(Product prod)
{
    var result = from p in dc.Products
                 where p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id
                 select p.product_price_kg;
    return result;
}
```

This gives me the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>`' to '`int`'

What's the best way to handle this? I need the price (which is an int in this case) and do some calculations with it in another place

Comment: What is the type of `Product.product_price_kg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've selected a *query* - that could in theory match 0, 1 or more records. What do you want to do in each situation? Also, it looks like `product_price_kg` is `int?` - what do you want to do if it's null?

You *might* want:

```
public int GetPricePerKg(Product prod)
{
    return dc.Products.Where(p => p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id)
                      .Select(p => p.product_price_kg)
                      .Single()
                      .Value;
}
```

... but that will throw an exception if *either* there isn't exactly one matching product *or* the price property is null.

You can still use a query expression if you want - but I tend not to for simple cases where you then want to add a method call at the end. The query expression equivalent is:

```
return (from p in dc.Products
        where p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id
        select p.product_price_kg).Single().Value;
```

Alternatively, you can use the version of `Single()` which takes a predicate, like this:

```
return dc.Products.Single(p => p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id)
                  .product_price_kg.Value;
```

There are no doubt other variations - they'll all do the same thing - pick whichever one you find most readable.

EDIT: Other options instead of `Single` are:

- `First` (cope with 1 or more)
- `FirstOrDefault` (cope with 0, 1 or more)
- `SingleOrDefault` (cope with 0 or 1)

For the `OrDefault` versions you'd need to work out what to do if you didn't match any products.

Comment: Maybe then `SingleOrDefault()` and check against null?

Answer (score 2):

you need to do (if you only want the first match  back)

```
public int GetPricePerKg(Product prod)
    {
        var result = (from p in dc.Products
                     where p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id
                     select p.product_price_kg).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Note that `default(int) == 0`

Comment: But `default(int?) == null`. This still won't compile, if `product_price_kg` is of type `int?` which is suggested by the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both John Skeet and saj are right in their answers. Here's just another alternate syntax more in line with the code you posted:

```
public int GetPricePerKg(Product prod)
{
    var result = from p in dc.Products
                 where p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id
                 select p.product_price_kg;
    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the addition. Looks logical, but that gives me the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Or since it was an 'int?', you could've used 'return result.FirstOrDefault().Value;

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `FristOrDefault()` extension method

```
public int GetPricePerKg(Product prod)
{
    var result = (from p in dc.Products
                 where p.pk_product_id == prod.pk_product_id
                 select p.product_price_kg).FirstOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```